# Problem on minted package on Windows 10 Pycharm

Tags: texmaker, minted, paths, python

I have a problem with minted package, because when I try to use it in my text editor (TeXmaker), it returns me the next error:

"You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package"

However, I already have installed pygmentize in Python's last version, and I configured the -shell-scape option, so I don't know what's going on. I read in github that maybe is a problem with the path, but I don't really know what it's happening.

Any help, please?

(btw, I use Windows 10 and Pycharm)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please try to run pygmentize from the command line.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! <3